# Requesting translation for clock-like image

Tags: перевод

Apologies if this question is not within the recognized scope of this forum.
I am wondering what the below might be. Some kind of clock?

[image: what is it?]

EDIT - Sorry for not giving more information. It was on the wall in a room of a formerly KGB-run hospital in Kiev. As it is not readily recognizable, I guess it may have some medical purpose.

The frame is from the highly recommended documentary 'The English Surgeon'.

Comment: It is very intriguingly. Where did you find this image?

Comment: Looks like a frame of a movie. In this case it should be related to movie's plot.

Comment: Dmitry points me in the right direction. I think it may be a eyesight test for patients suspected of papilledema.

Comment: Can it be a way to pick different cipher  "keys"? sort of like when you know the time - you know the key... or maybe I watched too many movies :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Russian alphabet goes А**Б**В**Г**ДЕЁЖЗИЙ**КЛ**М**НОПРСТ**У**ФХ**ЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ, so you can see that it's a selection of the letters arranged in alphabetical order, starting from Б on top and going clockwise. Why these particular twelve letters is anyone's guess. They don't correlate in any obvious way to numbers on a clock. If it's some kind of a combination lock or code dial, it might have parts missing. Also it might just turn out to be a faux-Russian prop from some foreign movie.